# How to clone a ghost.py session object?

Tags: python

Recently, I've tried to use ghost.py to click websites like a human.

For example, search google.com and get the search results.
Then click the result if that is I want.

In the results, there may be many elements that I need to click.

How can I click one and return to the search result website, then click another?

I tried code like this:

```
gh = Ghost()
with gh.start(display=True, user_agent=user_agent, viewport_size=viewport_size) as session:
    session.show()

if session.exists(selector=('a[href="%s"]' % a['href'])):
    print('执行点击 %s ' % clickkey)
    child_session = copy.copy(session)
    child_session.click(selector=('a[href="%s"]' % a['href']), btn=0)
    child_session.show()
    child_session.sleep(wait_time)
    child_session.exit()
```

After "child_session.exit()", session exits too.
How can I copy a session and do the click then do another click?

Thank you all.

Comment: What is a `session`? Have you tried `copy.deepcopy`?

Comment: i tried copy.deepcopy, and it excepted like this :
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object. i guess if copy.deepcopy cannot use in this situation..
a session is a ghost.Session instance .

Comment: Then you probably can't copy it, it's a complicated-looking object. Instead, why not just *not `.exit` it*, until you're finished? Pass the session object to other methods that click other things.

Comment: I tried passing session object to an other function, and it seems not work .The wrong reason looks like copy.copy()